# Information in a new CD/DVD disk

Tags: dvd, compact-disc, fingerprint

What information does a new disk (CD+RW or DVD+-R) contain? 
This can be inside of the disk or written physically on the disk.

Comment: Blank as in "new", or blank as in "erased"? A new disk will not contain anything apart from basic information such as capacity and maximum write speed. When you buy a new disk the surface is bright, but when you burn the disk you can see the new tracks created - often darker in colour - this shows there's nothing on the disk. An "erased" disk, however, may have one of two methods of "erase" - a quick erase which (like a hard disk) only erases the start of the disk so that writers are aware that the disk can be written to, or a full erase which, I'm guessing will overwrite full contents.

Comment: Regarding what DATA remnants are left on an "erased" disk, a quick erase will probably be recoverable, a "full erase" will physically burn the old data away, BUT there may always be bits of data left

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have correct the title of the question as well as the content itself.

Comment: Why do you think it has any content? Are you asking if it's always blank or always contains data? It could be different by brand... This question is not a good fit for this site (sorry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brand new CD-R/RWs and DVD-R/RWs do have some information on them.

Some of these information are relevant to the optical media burning software which use these information to correctly determine various aspects of the optical media like:

- Disc Manufacturer ([MID code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Identification_Code))
- Rated Speed
- Disc Capacity
- Disc Type

For more information, you might want to check out the [DVD Identifier](http://dvdidentifier.cdfreaks.com/) software and read an article about Absolute Time in Pregroove ([ATIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_Time_in_Pregroove)) [here](http://www.infocellar.com/CD/atip.htm).